# DLL возвращает значение в приложение, но не возвращает в службу

Tags: c#, dll, windows-service

Писал программу, которую надо теперь свернуть в службу. В программе используется библиотека стороннего приложения. Насколько понял, написана под .net, так как подключаю ее просто через reference и using.

В приложении все работает. Но когда перенес весь код в службу - используемые функции из dll не возвращают значений. Сделал лог, в который пишутся эти значения - постоянно пишутся пустые, но служба не падает.

Есть какие-то особенности использования dll из служб?

Кроме того, все происходит на Win Server 2012 R2 - могут быть нюансы? В качестве Account в инсталлере LocalSystem. После регистрации службы установил ей вход от имени пользователя, под которым приложение работает корректно.

```
[...]
using Proficy.iFixToolkit.Adapter2;

namespace SARDLoger
{
    public partial class SARDLoger : ServiceBase
    {

    static class LogWriter
    {
        public static void WriteToLog(string message)
        {
            using (StreamWriter stream = new StreamWriter(@"[...]\Log.txt", true))
                stream.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + "." + DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString() + " - " + message);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        FixReadWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void FixReadWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        float currentTagValue;      // Считанное значение тега

        while (!FixReadWorker.CancellationPending)
        {
            // Eda - класс из подключенной библиотеки
            // GetOneFloat(string node, string tag, string field, out float val);
            Eda.GetOneFloat("ThisNode", tag.fixTagName, "F_CV", out currentTagValue);
            LogWriter.WriteToLog(currentTagValue.ToString());
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Этого достаточно чтобы в приложении в currentTagValue попадало верное значение.

Comment: А что за библиотека? Есть ли доступ к исходникам?

Comment: @andreycha Нет, исходников и документации нету. Поэтому надеюсь на то что есть какие-то ошибки, которые часто допускаются при работе с библиотеками из сервисов, про которые я не знаю.

Comment: @BadIrbis ну давайте тогда примеры кода, где вы с библиотекой работаете

Comment: @Dmitry добавил в вопрос

Comment: @BadIrbis ваша служба работает в одном потоке?

Comment: @Dmitry нет, код с обращением к этому классу висит в background_worker

Comment: @BadIrbis а вы из потока передать значение в основной поток как пытаетесь? Думаю мой намек ясен?

Comment: Ну и потом, как вы хотите чтоб вам помогли, если вы не предоставили код? (тот что у вас указан в расчет не берем)

Comment: @Dmitry Дополнил код. Но не могу найти что не так с передачей значения в службе в отличие от приложения.

Comment: @Dmitry хочу напомнить, что служба *никогда* не работает в одном потоке. Если служба будет крутить цикл ожидания в основном потоке - то она будет считаться системой повисшей.

Answer (score 2):

Особых отличий службы от приложения, который были бы помехой *нормальному* коду, нет.

Вот список отличий:

- текущая директория службы - %windir%,
- служба не может создать окна на рабочем столе (но может создать невидимое),
- у службы обычно нет цикла обработки сообщений,
- у учетной записи службы отдельный профиль, если там хранились настройки - то теперь их нема.

---

Чтобы проверить гипотезу о цикле обработки оконных сообщений - попробуйте обратиться к библиотеке из консольного приложения. Если этот окажется, что в этом и дело - надо будет создать форму и работать с библиотекой из нее:

```
private ApplicationContext app;
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    app = new ApplicationContext(new MyForm());
    new Thread(Run).Start();
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    app.ExitThread();
}

private void Run()
{
    // Обязательно вызывать Application.Run в отдельном потоке, иначе служба "зависнет" и перестанет отвечать на сигналы
    // ApplicationContext используется потому что без контекста нельзя вызвать ExitThread другому потоку
    Application.Run(app);
}
```

В принципе, можно обойтись и без формы - но тогда нужно будет наследоваться  `ApplicationContext` и что-нибудь перегружать, потому что по умолчанию без формы цикл обработки сообщений сразу же завершается.

---

Если же дело не в отличиях, перечисленных выше - остается только реверс-инженеринг. Тут можно пойти двумя путями:

1. декомпиляция - берем [IlSpy](http://ilspy.net/) и вперед;
2. изучение внешнего поведения - берем [ProcessMonitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) и сравниваем системные вызовы, которые делаются библиотекой при нормальной работе и ненормальной.